# Jquery Draggable disabled style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a draggabe function for object which is working fine. Also I have a simple toggle button which is doing:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable( "disable" );
```

After make draggable disabled the object is getting grey (like disabled button). I don't want that. I know it needs to be changed in CSS but i don't know where. Appreciate your help

Comment: I setup this test in jsFiddle and can't reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/WF588/1/ can you create a jsFiddle where the problem appears?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working when i will do this like you. Staticly. Problem exist when you add a button to enable and disable draggable object. Then it will be grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a button inside the draggable item jQueryUI decides to add the class `ui-state-disabled` to the element.

Try something like this on the button that disables the draggable item:

```
$('input').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#dragMeButton').draggable("disable").removeClass("ui-state-disabled"); 
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WF588/3/)